# Get the path of the parent of the parent of an AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Is there an easy way to get the path of the grandparent of an AppleScript itself?
Currently I have:

```
set grandparent to POSIX file (POSIX path of ((POSIX file (POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")) as text) & "::")) as text
```

This works, but is kind of cumbersome. Especially when I would need the great-grandparent of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
tell application "System Events" to set grandparent to path of container of container of (path to me)
```